# Find elemtnt*s* return array with same element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been up on this for 2 days.

Trying to get all Text(s) from span(s), which appear in many div(s).

All the div(s) looks pretty much the same :

```
<div class="_3_7SH _3DFk6 message-in">
<div class="Tkt2p">
<div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[10:26 AM, 5/28/2019] יוסף צדוק: ">
<div class="_3zb-j ZhF0n">
<span dir="rtl" class="XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">TEXT TO COPY IS ME</span></div></div>
<div class="_2f-RV"><div class="_1DZAH">
<span class="_1ORuP">
</span><span class="_3EFt_">10:26 AM</span></div></div></div><span></span></div>
```

This is how tried to find ALL "message-in" elements :

`in_mesg_arr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-in')]")`

I got back the length of the array: `11`

Then, tried to get all text from span(s):

```
for index in in_mesg_arr:
   last_msg = last_msg + str(index.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//span[contains(@class,'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')]").text)
```

HOWEVER, i get back the same text (same element over and over!).

print(last_msg) = bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Will be glad to get some directions.

FULL HTML:

Comment: Instead of providing a handcrafted HTML, update the question with text based actual relevant HTML for a detailed analysis.

Comment: How is `last_msg` defined?

Comment: I've EDITED PLEASE REVIEW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for index in last_msg:
   last_msg = last_msg + str(in_mesg_arr[index].find_element_by_xpath(
    "//span[contains(@class,'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')]").text)
```

This code will always returns the 1st element because it will search `span` element any where in the `DOM`.

The `XPath` expression in the loop has to start with a `dot` to be context-specific.Use any of the following code.

```
 in_mesg_arr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-in')]")
    for item in in_mesg_arr:
        spanele=item.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')]")
        print(spanele.text)
```

OR

```
in_mesg_arr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'message-in')]")

for item in range(len(in_mesg_arr)):
    spanele=in_mesg_arr[item].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')]")
    print(spanele.text)
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: index is a webElement not int, so i changed it to >>
index.find_element_by....
now it says that "no such element: Unable to locate element:"
BUT its there... any ideas what to do?

Comment: I've EDITED please review

Answer (score 0):

These can be done using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '''
    <div> class = "*something* message-in *something*" <div>
    <span> class = "selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" <span>
    '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")

span_text =  [x.get_text() for x in  soup.find_all('span')]



html_con = '''
<div class="_3_7SH _3DFk6 message-in">
<div class="Tkt2p">
<div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[10:26 AM, 5/28/2019] יוסף צדוק: ">
<div class="_3zb-j ZhF0n">
<span dir="rtl" class="XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">TEXT TO COPY IS ME</span></div></div>
<div class="_2f-RV"><div class="_1DZAH">
<span class="_1ORuP">
</span><span class="_3EFt_">10:26 AM</span></div></div></div><span></span></div>
<div class="_3_7SH _3DFk6123456 message-in">
<div class="Tkt2p">
<div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[10:26 AM, 5/28/2019] יוסף צדוק: ">
<div class="_3zb-j ZhF0n">
<span dir="rtl" class="XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">New text</span></div></div>
<div class="_2f-RV"><div class="_1DZAH">
<span class="_1ORuP">
</span><span class="_3EFt_">10:26 AM</span></div></div></div><span></span></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_con)

content_message_in= soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'message-in'})
span_content =[x.find_all('span') for x in content_message_in]
span_text  = [x[0].get_text() for x in span_content]


#o/p
['TEXT TO COPY IS ME', 'New text']
```

Comment: I need to find many of those "message-in" and in them, I need to find the span.
how could I find all elements by partial class name with BeautifulSoup? @qaiser

Comment: i have added another div section which contain class name message-in, and added new string   "New text " . hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that when you are getting the spans, you are using

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

instead of

```
find_elements_by_xpath
```

So its just returning the first element that matches, every time.

see the answer for this question:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/find-elements-by-xpath-issue?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I am using find_elementS_by_xpath. still returning the same one